# Flaw in logic of Conditional probability

Tags: probability

A box contains $3$ coins, $2$ of them being fair and one two headed coin. A coin is selected at random and tossed twice. If heads appear both times find the probability that coin is two headed?

We have to find P(Coin is two headed $\mid$ Heads appear both times ). Let us interpret it as P(A$\mid$B). If we take B to be sample space that is heads appear both times. There are $3$ ways in which this can happen and the two headed coin is our requirement so probability should be $\frac{1}{3}$.

Where am I going wrong in my approach?

Comment: The three ways are not equally probable.  If I choose a fair coin, then there is only a $\frac 14$ chance that I see $HH$.  To gain intuition for this, suppose I tossed the coin a trillion times and saw a trillion $H's$.  Then you can be effectively certain that you have the two-headed coin.

Comment: Draw a tree diagram.  In the first branching, we choose a coin, so the branches are each weighted $1/3$.  In the second branching, we perform the first flip.  In the third branching, we perform the second flip.  We end up with a set of events that show the coin selected and the result of each flip: $\{(fair 1, H, H), (fair 1, H, T), ...(two-headed, H, H)\}$.  Now calculate the probability of each and use the fact that $P(A|B) = P(A\intersection B)/P(B).$

Comment: The content of this question is fine, but I find the title of this question a little melodramatic and click-baity. Do you mind changing it to something more informative? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the event that you have picked the two-headed coin and $B$ be the event that you see two heads in a row. Then from
$$P(A)\>P(B|A)=P(A\cap B)= P(B)\>P(A|B) $$
we obtain Bayes' formula
$$P(A|B)={P(A)\>P(B|A)\over P(B)}\ .$$
In the case at hand $P(A)={1\over3}$, $P(B|A)=1$, and $$P(B)={1\over3}\cdot1+{2\over3}\cdot{1\over4}={1\over2}\ .$$
It follows that $P(A|B)={2\over3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let the coins be named $X_1,X_2,Y$, where $Y$ has two heads.

Consider the experiment "pick a coin and flip it twice".  The sample space for outcomes for that is:

$$\{X_1,H,H\},\{X_1,H,T\},\{X_1,T,H\},\{X_1,T,T\}$$

$$\{X_2,H,H\},\{X_2,H,T\},\{X_2,T,H\},\{X_2,T,T\}$$

each of which having probability $$\frac 13 \times \frac 12\times\frac 12=\frac 1{12}$$

and

$$\{Y,H,H\}$$

having probability $$\frac 13$$

Sanity check: note that the total probability is $8\times \frac 1{12}+\frac 13=1$

If you now tell me that you have tried this and observed $HH$ I see that I must have achieved one of $\{X_1,H,H\},\{X_2,H,H\},\{Y,H,H\}$.  The probability that I realized one of these outcomes is $\frac 1{12}+\frac 1{12}+\frac 13=\frac 12$  So the conditional probability in question is $$\frac {\frac 13}{\frac 1{2}}=\frac 23$$